# Need to pass argument to modal dlg from Datatable button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I do use datatable where i've been declared some buttons to trigger action based which button user press:

```
var dpcroles = $('#example_roles').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Add',
            id: 'btn_add',
            "data-action":'add',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                $('#modal_action').modal();
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'btn_edit',
            text: 'Edit',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
                console.log(id);
                $('#model_action').modal(id);
            },
            enabled: true
        },

    ],
```

However, how to pass arguments javascript which handles modal opening ?

```
$('#model_action').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // if button 'edit', do something 
        .
        . 
    // else if button 'add' do other thing 
        .
        .
        .
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `data-` attribute for a modal before calling `modal()` method. For example:

```
$('#modal_action').data('mode', 'edit');
$('#modal_action').modal();
```

Then in your event handler, you can retrieve the data. For example:

```
$('#modal_action').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $modal = $(this);

    var mode = $modal.data('mode');

    // if button 'edit', do something 
    if(mode === 'edit'){

    // else if button 'add' do other thing 
    } else {

    }
});
```

Another solution would be to use two different modals, one for each action.

Please note that you've probably misspelled the name of the modal in your example, it should be either `modal_action` or `model_action`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it does works. Thank you. Above code sample I made misspelling error during when I cleaned code for public review.